# VMWare workstation won't start after crashing

Tags: macos, crash, virtual-machine

I'm running mac OS using VMware workstation on my windows 7 PC. Today unfortunately my PC shutdown due to power issue and I couldn't shutdown guest OS properly. Now I'm trying to open mac os but VMware is continuously crashing. Please let me know if any solution.My VMware error log is enclosed

[vmware.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1p2B0i44TLtxebO6e__PmFwIRnplu_TRz)

Thank You.

Comment: You didnt post your log

Comment: I have attached log file now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method:

1) Clean start Windows 7, and make a copy of you MacOS VMWare directory.

2) In the new copy directory, remove *.vmem, *.nvram, and *.lck

3) Start MacOS guest from copy directory.

Comment: I didn't find *.vmem in my directory

Answer (score 0):

In any case, if we end up getting a crashed VM, we can still recover the data from the VM by extracting the files using 7Zip.

1 - Download and Install 7Zip.

2 - Navigate to VM folder and extract the file - (.vmdk)

3 - Navigate to extracted folder -

4 - Now extract the file - Disc Image File (.img)

5 - Navigate to the extracted folder and open the home folder.

Hurrey, You have all your data available in the VM.